# ngTagsInput disabled input after max tag number

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have a question, maybe someone used `ngTagsInput` in yours applications.

Is there an option to disable the input after you insert a max tags amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngTagsInput` has an ngModel accepting the array of tags so you can use `ngDisabled` to disable the input.

Problem is if your input is disabled you wouldn't be able to remove any already existing tags and further edit the input. I wouldn't advice doing it.

However you have some alternatives...

1. Validate the amount of tags you have

The [API docs](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api) state that `max-tags` attribute is used to validate the max amount of tags inside the input, when you exceed the limit, the validation state will turn to `$invalid`, you can then prevent form submission.

> maxTags - number - 
>   Sets maxTags validation error key if the number of tags added is greater than maxTags.

For example:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" max-tags="7">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

2. Use the `on-tag-added` callback attribute to catch when the user exceeds the allowed tags number and just remove any new tag he enters without playing around with validation flags

**HTML:**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" 
    on-tag-added="onTagAdded($query, 7)"></tags-input>
<p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.onTagAdded = function(tag, limit) {
    if ($scope.tags.length == limit+1) {
        $scope.tags.pop();
    }
}
```

In the above examples, we limit tags amount to 7.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found third way, e.g. if you want max 4 tags, set max-tags="3" and in invalid css style set display none

Comment: will that also prevent the tags array from growing ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think yes